# Error with cryptography, cffi on Apple M1 processor

Tags: python, macos, pip, cryptography, apple-m1

My system:
Apple M1 Max, Ventura 13.0.1

Python 3.8.15
Pip 22.3.1

Trying to install project, by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`
`requirements.txt` contains:
https://privatebin.net/?a124b74f822ae43b#HxpLMnYwSz5hKqvv129A5Qpq4n3WsnYRW8JiJntXLVZN

Here's the error output I get:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: cffi, numpy, pillow, reportlab
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi

Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Failed to build cffi numpy pillow reportlab
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Full output: https://privatebin.net/?99bd0ca11b7969e0#Bg6rjoznhdzekjPD82G5Myou1m5kHjPtaxhrZQUJxdSm

I would be very grateful for any help!

I tried upgrading pip, installing pillow, cryptography, cffi, numpy manually. Re-installed project and recreated venv a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my way of resolving.
Delete the system/delete the user on your Mac and first thing first, install Rosetta 2.
After it, run your Terminal in Rosetta mode and install Python + all the requirements using the Terminal in Rosetta mode.

Comment: This answer is fine, but I'd leave off the "quite simple" comment, since this is only one solution to a potentially much more complicated issue. EG terminals compiled for intel, will set architecture env vars to intel_64 (vs arm64), and compilers in pip/python may respect that. You can also override those variables and cause different behavior.